# Using RTRIM in JOIN condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, select, join

I want to put two tables which are containing Products together by their DESCRIPTIONs

`TABLE 1: [..fields..] [DESCRIPTION1] [..fields..]`

`TABLE 2: [..fields..] [DESCRIPTION2] [..fields..]`

```
SELECT [..fields..] FROM TABLE1,TABLE2 
    INNER JOIN TABLE1 
    ON TABLE1.DESCRIPTION1 = TABLE2.DESCRIPTION2
```

But in lots of cases, there are descriptions in both tables ending with an space, i also want to get them, thatswhy i tried it that way:

```
SELECT [..fields..] FROM TABLE1,TABLE2 
    INNER JOIN TABLE1 
    ON TABLE1.DESCRIPTION1 = TABLE2.DESCRIPTION2 
    OR RTRIM(TABLE1.DESCRIPTION1) = RTRIM(TABLE2.DESCRIPTION2)
```

Which produces no error, but does not bring more data.

Is anybody able to help me?

Every help is appreciated :)

Thanks in Advance, Harry

Comment: How do you know the problem is trailing spaces? What are the data types of the two description columns? Also do you really mean to write `FROM table1, table2 INNER JOIN table1`?

Comment: both are varchar, and I know its because of the spaces, because i found lots of descriptions in TABLE1 which are ending with a space :|

Comment: `FROM table1, table2 INNER JOIN table1` is quite the code Microsoft SQL Server Manager generated, is there an easier way?

Comment: Just because there are spaces doesn't mean that's why your join isn't returning any rows. Especially since RTRIM, which removes all trailing spaces, doesn't fix it.

Comment: While I wouldn't be 100% shocked, I don't think Management Studio produced that code on its own. Can you explain how you got it to produce old-style inner joins?

Comment: `SELECT [..fields..] FROM TABLE1 
    INNER JOIN TABLE2 
    ON TABLE1.DESCRIPTION1 = TABLE2.DESCRIPTION2 
    OR RTRIM(TABLE1.DESCRIPTION1) = RTRIM(TABLE2.DESCRIPTION2)` Well its a bad typo like i recognized now, but it looks like it does above these sentence.

Comment: its strange, because lots of data aneds with a space, but rtrim does not improve the join in that way.. `SELECT DESCRIPTION1 FROM TABLE1 WHERE DESCRIPTION1 LIKE '% '` returns about one third of all data

Comment: like i mentioned below: Problem is solved thx to all :D RTRIM worked fine, CRLF and strange Spaces inside the Descriptions had been the problem :)

Comment: So it sounds to me like they weren't "spaces" at all...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem might be CRLF characters at the end of the Description, which will look like spaces in SSMS and won't be removed by `RTRIM()`.

To check, see if selecting `where Description like '%' + char(13) + char(10)` returns anything.  If it looks like there is only 1 space at the end of the Description, try either `char(13)` or `char(10)` alone.  Finally, a Tab (`char(9)`) would also look like a space, so you could try that as well.

If it does turn out to be any of these characters, you could use `REPLACE` to get rid of them:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(MyField, CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(9), '')
```

which I found [here](http://metadeveloper.blogspot.com/2006/03/remove-carriage-return-line-feed-tab.html).

Comment: That really looks promising, and would kind of explain why there is a difference in LEN() and DATALEN(), thanks so far, I report if it solves the issue

Comment: that was really helpful. A combination of this, and Spaces inside the Description had been the problem. Thankx to you and all the other who helped me :)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the OR

```
SELECT [..fields..] 
  FROM TABLE1 T1
       INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2
         ON RTRIM(T1.DESCRIPTION1) = RTRIM(T2.DESCRIPTION2)
```

Comment: `OR` is perfectly ok here. The reason for it is to make use of index on `description` (surely,if it exists).

Comment: @a1ex07 - you bring up a valid point.  In the case of a one-shot conversion I would not normally care about the performance, but it might matter if the table is large, so always better to be safe.

Comment: @Leons : I see; it looks like it wasn't intentionally made for performance sake as I initially thought.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the data type, you shouldn't need RTRIM() at all. I also wonder if your mix of old-style and modern join syntax is tripping you up (though that should yield more rows, not less). What does this yield?

```
SELECT [..columns..]
    FROM dbo.TABLE1 AS t1
    INNER JOIN dbo.TABLE2 AS t2
    ON RTRIM(t1.DESCRIPTION1) = RTRIM(t2.DESCRIPTION2);
```

Comment: Whether it fixes the specific problem or not mixing implicit and explict joins can create problems and should not be done. Isn't almost 20 years long enough to put up with people using this long ago replaced syntax? Can't we deprecate and be done with it?

Comment: @HLGEM old-style inner joins are still not deprecated (as much as, like you, I wish they would just trash them already). Only old-style outer joins (`*=`/`=*`) are finally non-functional. So you can still keep generating inadvertent Cartesian products to your heart's content! :-)